# Subclassing without the class keyword

Tags: javascript

How does the following look in terms of constructing a subclass from objects without using the `class` keyword as a sort of academic exercise?

```js
// Product > Book
function Product(type, price) {
    if (!new.target) return new Product(...arguments);
    console.log('--- Product.constructor() ---');
    Object.assign(this, {type, price});
}
Product.prototype.getPrice = function getPrice() {
    console.log('--- Product.getPrice() ---');
    return this.price;
}
Product.prototype.display = function displayProduct() {
    console.log('--- Product.display() ---');
    return `${this.type} (${this.price})`;
}

// subclass the Product
function Book(type, price, title, author, pages) {
    if (!new.target) return new Book(...arguments);
    console.log('--- Book.constructor() ---');
    Object.assign(this, new Product(type, price), {title, author, pages});
    this.parent = Product;
}
Book.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
Book.prototype.constructor = Book;
Book.prototype.getNumPages = function() {
    console.log('--- Book.getNumPages() ---');
    return this.pages;
}
Book.prototype.display = function displayBook() {
    console.log('--- Book.display() ---');
    return `${this.parent.prototype.display.call(this)}`
         + ` -- ${this.title} by ${this.author} (${this.pages} pgs)`;
}

console.log(Product.prototype);
console.log(Book.prototype, Book.prototype.constructor === Book);

let book = Book("Book", 4.99, "Angels", "Dan Brown", 305);
console.log(book.getNumPages());
console.log(book.getPrice());
console.log(book.display());
```

Does it seems like anything is missing in the above or can be improved? One question I was a bit perplexed on -- why doesn't the `this` get updated automatically when calling the parent constructor, which requires doing this (passing the return value of the `Product` constructor rather that it just updating `this` as a sort of side-effect:

```
Object.assign(this, new Product(type, price), {title, author, pages});
```

Comment: Why are you using `if (!new.target) return new Product(...arguments);`? This prevents a standard ES5 super call `Product.call(this, type, price)`.

Comment: "*How does the following look*" sounds like a question better suited for [codereview.SE] (although they prefer real production code)

Comment: "*`this.parent = Product;`*" is weird. What's the purpose? If anything, you'd better place `Book.parent = Product` outside of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the required pattern is:

```
        // the base class constructor
        function Product(type, price) {
           this.type = type;
           this.price = price;
        }

        // include the public properties in the prototype chain
        Product.prototype.type = null;
        Product.prototype.price = null;
    
        // base class public methods that are going to be inherited
        Product.prototype.display = function displayProduct() {
           console.log(this.type, this.price);
        }
    
        // the class that is going to inherit from Product class    
        function Book(type, price, title, author, pages) {
           // apply the constructor method of the base class to define those properties in this scope
           Product.call(this, type, price);
        }
        // inherit the base class prototype (overrides the constructor)
        Book.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
    
       // restore the original inherited class constructor
        Book.prototype.constructor = Book;



    var book = new Book('adventure', 30, 'once upon a time', 'Jim Books', 10);
    book.display(); // will display: adventure 30
```

Trying to assemble an inherited object using spread won't work as expected, as you'll end up with an object containing only a prototype.

Comment: Thanks -- for some reason doing `Product.call(this, type, price);` doesn't update the `this` object, it returns an object.

Comment: what do you mean by update the this object? this will always refer to the scope where it is being called from. if Object call does not result in the inheritance of the 'type' and 'price' arguments, try define them in the prototype as in the example above.

Comment: "*include the public properties in the prototype chain*" is weird. Why do that? They get created on every instance anyway.

Comment: I know, yet check the differences by running the above code on a browser, inspect the Product.prototype after being defined (not Product.[[Prototype]]) and see the differences that including/excluding the public vars result in the prototype chain.

Comment: Anyway, the above code achieves inheritance successfully.